# JavaFX 2.0 Automatic install of dll file

Tags: java, dll, serial-port, javafx-2

I am currently doing an application that uses serial port using RxTx library. That app will be used by many computers, most of all will be used by unexperienced users.

It is necessary to put the appropiate DLL (rxtxSerial.dll) in the correct Java path but I think that most of the users won't be able to do that task. 
Does somebody know how to install this DLL transparently to the correct path?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Include the DLL in your JAR and in a static initializer in your code do the following:

- copy DLL to TMPDIR
- `System.load("full/path/to/DLL/in/TMPDIR")`

Should work everywhere, does not need an experienced user and no installer.

See [here](https://github.com/rjeschke/jpa/tree/master/src/java/com/github/rjeschke/jpa) for an example (static block in `JPA` and `LibraryLoader` class)

Comment: Hi Neet, I tried your proposal but it doesn't work well, i'm having the same error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver